# Bazel pkg_files in another workspace

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have a complicated project which Bazel tree looks like this:

```
MainFolder
|
├── Folder1
│   └── Subfolder1
│   |   ├── BUILD
|   |WORKSPACE
├── Folder2
│   └── Subfolder2
│   |   |─── SubSubfolder2
│   |        ├── BUILD
|   |WORKSPACE
```

Basically there are some files being generated (not important) and they are being generated in the BUILD of Subfolder1.
What I need, is for these files to be packaged to SubSubfolder2. How can I achieve this?

I read somewhere that I need to create a WORKSPACE file in the outmost level (MainFolder) and I tried it but it didn't work. Or maybe I didn't do it correctly, I just added the one file.

I am using following command:

```
pkg_files(
    name = "files",
    srcs = [ # list of files #],
    prefix = "", # what should be written here?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to obtain anything from beyond the workspace is by using [external dependency](https://bazel.build/external/overview). In your case [`bzlmod`](https://bazel.build/external/overview#bzlmod) isn't all that applicable, hence [WORKSPACE](https://bazel.build/external/overview#workspace-system) file and repository rule. Namely for another repo in the filesystem: [local_repository](https://bazel.build/reference/be/workspace#local_repository). You could say in `Folder2/WORKSPACE` something like:

```
local_repository(
    name = "other_repo1",
    path = "../Folder1",
)
```

And then in a `BUILD` you could refer to labels provided by that workspace using labels such as:  `@other_repo1//Subfolder1:some_target_label`.

Needless to say... "complicated" is not a good layout for a tree setup. And esp. if one project (workspace) depends on something build in the other project... and esp. if the external dependency was to be defined on another path at a known location. Essentially, is it really the correct setup?